# How to reorder controls of WYSIWYG editor

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, wysiwyg

I am using https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg which is showing

```
B I U
```

as controls and I want to change the order of the controls so **bold** is not show first as the option.

I looked into the source code and in https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg/blob/master/jquery.wysiwyg.css, saw

```
div.wysiwyg ul.toolbar li.bold { background-position: -1px -15px; }
div.wysiwyg ul.toolbar li.italic { background-position: -18px -15px; }
```

so I changed it to

```
div.wysiwyg ul.toolbar li.bold { background-position: -18px -15px; }
div.wysiwyg ul.toolbar li.italic { background-position: -1px -15px; }
```

now in the editor, I is before B but when I click, I, it still bolds and when I click B, it is still italic. How to fix this ? also is there anyway to not edit the main jquery.wysiwyg.css file and just override .css and .js code ? I am using RubyonRails btw

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alter the sequence of the bold and italic property in the source code of **wysiwyg.js**

i simply altered the position of the following code

```
bold: {
            groupIndex: 0,
            visible: true,
            tags: ["b", "strong"],
            css: {
                fontWeight: "bold"
            },
            tooltip: "Bold",
            hotkey: {"ctrl": 1, "key": 66}
        },
```

and

```
italic: {
            groupIndex: 0,
            visible: true,
            tags: ["i", "em"],
            css: {
                fontStyle: "italic"
            },
            tooltip: "Italic",
            hotkey: {"ctrl": 1, "key": 73}
        },
```

however, i didn't changed any css but still it is working fine. By default the **bold:** property is the first property passed in the **this.controls** object in the **wysiwyg.js** file, not sure why it is still working even without modifying the css file.

**Edit:**

**Demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/M2uKK/2/

i added the source code of all the js and css files required in the fiddle itself since i was unable to find cdns for them. images will not be available but you can still see that the first and second option are italic and bold.

**Note:** the only change i made here is altering the position of the bold and italic properties as i have described earlier.

Comment: strange, in jquery.wysiwyg.js file, I moved the I code to B and B code to I still, B is the first element and I is the second one, any idea what is wrong ?

Comment: please view the fiddle. Have you undone your css changes after altering the positions?

Answer (score 0):

WHat you are editing are the sprites of the items. There is a background with all the images needed in the page, put one to the side of the other, and then in every element you adjust the position of this large image to show only the part required for the element.

So, you are changing only the image displayed.

It's difficult to say how could you achieve what you want without seeing more code. May be some relative positioning ?